# Организация связи между членами одного класса

Tags: c++, классы, callback

Пусть для примера есть класс, который осуществляет общение с внешним интерфейсом и периодически получает байт (сделано в виде отдельного потока внутри самого класса). Этот байт в момент получения должен быть передан "старшему" классу и сохранен в очередь. То есть структура примерно следующая:

```
class A {
    B b;
    std::queue<uint8_t> q;
}
class B {
    uint8_t byte;
}
```

Как правильно организовать передачу byte из объекта b в очередь q?

Я пытался сделать в классе B callback функцию:

```
class B {
    uint8_t byte;
    void saveCallbackFunction(void (*callback)(uint8_t byte));
    void (*callbackFunction)(uint8_t byte);
}
```

И в классе A:

```
class A {
    B b;
    void putByteToQueue(uint8_t byte);
    std::queue<uint8_t> q;
}
```

Соответственно после создания объекта b в объекте a вызывается

```
b.saveCallbackFunction(putByteToQueue);
```

Естественными образом возникает конфликт между A::putByteToQueue и просто void.

Как осуществить такой механизм взаимодействия корректно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`putByteToQueue` не может быть значением аргумента типа `void (*)(uint8_t)`, потому что имеет тип `void (A::*)(uint8_t)`. Соответстственно, варианты, по степени возрастания элегантности:

1. Передавать `B` ссылку на `q` при создании:

   ```
   B::B(std::queue<uint8_t> &);
   ```
2. Вызывать из `B` метод `A`:

   ```
   B::B(A &parent): parent(parent) {}
   void B::receive(uint8_t byte) { parent.q.push_back(byte); }
   ```

   Можно еще добавить второй аргумент, получив oldschool callback:

   ```
   B::B(A &parent, void (A::*method)(uint8_t)): parent(parent), method(method) {}
   void B::receive(uint8_t byte) { (parent.*method)(byte); }
   ```
3. Сделать callback (точнее, функциональный объект) правильного типа:

   ```
   B::B(std::function<void(uint8_t)> f): f(std::move(f)) {}
   // ну или вариант:
   template<class F> B(F &&f): f(std::forward<F>(f)) {}

   A::A(): b([this](uint8_t byte){ q.push_back(byte); }) {}
   ```

   Вместо анонимной функции в последнем случае можно использовать `std::bind`.

Comment: 1. Об этом думал, но так как один поток будет производить загрузку байт в очередь, а в классе A будет проводиться разбор элементов, то я хотел реализовать мьютексы, что не получится (насколько я понимаю) при этом подходе. Тогда придётся еще и сам мьютекс передавать по ссылке.
2. Класс B хотелось бы сделать чисто автономным, не зависящим от типа его 'мастера'. В этом случае, правда, можно спастись наследованием.
3. Третий вариант попробую, спасибо!